# Expanding td width beyond the size of the container

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I can't figure out how to expand a td width beyond the size of the container. To see what I mean, check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dkXtw/4/) jsFiddle.

Once the table fills the container width, I can't make the cells any wider. Provided I need to do it after the page has loaded, how would I go about doing this?

I **don't** really want to resize the containing div.

Comment: You might consider resizing the table instead of the cells. It's probably a good thing in most cases that `td`s can't overflow a table.

Comment: @Rob see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538243/expanding-td-width-problem/6538322#6538322 :-D

Comment: How can you make this, if there's no place in container? (Because "the table fills the container width".) Or I do not understand, what you need.

Comment: That is a strange problem. The best solution I've found so far is this: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/pjpLT/

Comment: @Webars I simplified my project down to this representative example... I have a good reason for doing this so don't worry. :)

Comment: @minitech What is going on there?

Comment: @chrislegend: I set the `padding-right` instead of the width. It only works because the text is left-aligned though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expand the size of the table (not the outer div):
 http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dkXtw/15/

```
$("#testTable").width($("#testTable").width()  + 100 );
```

Comment: @chrislegend -- no problem ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The cells are not individual elements, they are always part of the table. The table just uses the size that you set on the cells as a recommendation on how to distribute the available space, when the specified widths conflict with the dimensions that you have set for the table (which in this case is limited by the surrounding element), the widths are just used to weigh the cells against each other.